# Hadoop: Using cgroups for TaskTracker tasks

Tags: linux, hadoop, linux-kernel, cgroups

Is it possible to configure `cgroups` or Hadoop in a way that each process that is spawned by the TaskTracker is assigned to a specific cgroup?

I want to enforce memory limits using `cgroups`. It is possible to assign a cgroup to the TaskTracker but if jobs wreak havoc the TaskTracker will be probably also killed by the `oom-killer` because they are in the same group.

Let's say I have 8GB memory on a machine. I want to reserve 1,5GB for the DataNode and system utilities and let the Hadoop TaskTracker use 6,5GB of memory. Now I start a Job using the streaming API at spawns 4 mappers and 2 reducers (each of these could in theory use 1GB RAM) that eats more memory than allowed. Now the `cgroup` memory limit will be hit and oom-killer starts to kill a job. I would rather use a cgroup for each Map and Reduce task e.g. a `cgroup` that is limited to 1GB memory.

Is this a real or more theoretical problem? Would the `oom-killer` really kill the Hadoop TaskTracker or would he start killing the forked processes first? If the latter is most of the time true my idea would probably work. If not - a bad job would still kill the TaskTracker on all cluster machines and require manual restarts.

Is there anything else to look for when using cgroups?

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the hadoop parameters that allow the to set and max the heap allocations for the tasktracker's child processes (tasks) and also do not forget to look at the reuse of jvm possibility.

useful links:

http://allthingshadoop.com/2010/04/28/map-reduce-tips-tricks-your-first-real-cluster/

http://developer.yahoo.com/hadoop/tutorial/module7.html

[How to avoid OutOfMemoryException when running Hadoop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3383402/how-to-avoid-outofmemoryexception-when-running-hadoop)

http://www.quora.com/Why-does-Hadoop-use-one-JVM-per-task-block

Comment: Yes. The problem is `ulimit` only addresses virtual memory and because of this it's difficult to set good limits and streaming tasks do not fall under the limits for Java jobs. I need some robust solution as the cluster will be used by lot's of students and staff and should work without any problems.

Answer (score 0):

If it's that you have lot of students and staff accessing the Hadoop cluster for job submission, you can probably look at Job Scheduling in Hadoop.

Here is the gist of some types you may be interested in -

**Fair scheduler:**
The core idea behind the fair share scheduler was to assign resources to jobs such that on average over time, each job gets an equal share of the available resources. 
To ensure fairness, each user is assigned to a pool. In this way, if one user submits many jobs, he or she can receive the same share of cluster resources as all other users (independent of the work they have submitted).

**Capacity scheduler:**
In capacity scheduling, instead of pools, several queues are created, each with a configurable number of map and reduce slots. Each queue is also assigned a guaranteed capacity (where the overall capacity of the cluster is the sum of each queue's capacity). Capacity scheduling was defined for large clusters, which may have multiple, independent consumers and target applications.

Here's the link from where I shamelessly copied the above mentioned things, due to lack of time.
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-hadoop-scheduling/index.html

To configure Hadoop use this link: http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.1.1/fair_scheduler.html#Installation